# d3.js - Collision in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement the [following script](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) in v4:

*This script is written in v3 and is not valid in v4.*
(I'm also new to d3 and started to learn v4)

```js
var width = 400,
    height = 400;

var nodes = d3.range(200).map(function() { return {radius: Math.random() * 12 + 4}; }),
    root = nodes[0],
    color = d3.scale.category10();

root.radius = 0;
root.fixed = true;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height]);

force.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes.slice(1))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i % 3); });

force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));

  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
});

function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 16,
      nx1 = node.x - r,
      nx2 = node.x + r,
      ny1 = node.y - r,
      ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
          y = node.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The best solution I could think of is to move around a big special circle and use collision to avoid the rest of the circles touch my big circle.

But my big circle is freezing. 
In addition, think my overall solution is not so good:

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var width = 1000,
    height = 600;

d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 600);

const collideCircle = {
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'black',
    center: {
        x: 200,
        y: 200
    }
};

const radius = 10;
const moreCircles = [...Array(40).keys()].map(i => ({
    radius,
    fill: 'pink',
    center: {
        x: 200,
        y: 200
    }
}));

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation([collideCircle, ...moreCircles])
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x(d => d.center.x))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(d => d.center.y))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => d.radius))
    .on('tick', ticked);

const collideCircles = d3.select('svg')
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data([collideCircle])
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('fill', d => d.fill)
    .attr('r', d => d.radius)
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y);

const moreCirclesGeom = d3.select('svg')
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(moreCircles)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('fill', d => d.fill)
    .attr('r', d => d.radius)
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y);

function ticked() {
    // stay in the SVG (box) only:

    moreCirclesGeom
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x));
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y));
        });

    collideCircles
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x));
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y));
        });
}

d3.select('svg').on("mouseover", handleMouseOver);

function handleMouseOver() {
    collideCircle.fx = d3.event.x;
    collideCircle.fy = d3.event.y;

    simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try mousemove rather than mouseover (it's mousemove in the v3 example), seems to result in the desired outcome.

Comment: Yeah, it was the problem. Thank you! But over-all, from the example I provided, they chose another way which I can't fully understand.

Comment: why don't you use `d.radius` in `tick()`? you can use `d3.range(40)` instead of the `Array(40).keys()`